# PIR sensor always HIGH when used with other sensors

Tags: arduino

i'm facing a problem with my ESP32 project because of the PIR sensor. when I use it with other sensors it always sends high voltage even tho it works fine when implemented alone. tried to use different pins for it but the issue still persists. does anybody know how to fix this bug?

here is the code used:

```
#include <DHTesp.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <MQ2.h>

#ifndef ESP32
#pragma message(THIS EXAMPLE IS FOR ESP32 ONLY!)
#error Select ESP32 board.
#endif

const char* ssid = "Mynetwork";
const char* password = "********";

const uint16_t port = 8090;
const char * host = "***********";

const int dhtPin = 18;
const int waterPin = 26;
const int mq2Pin   = 2;
const int pirPin = 25;

int factor=0;

DHTesp dht;
MQ2 mq2(mq2Pin);

void setup() {


  pinMode(pirPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(waterPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(mq2Pin,INPUT);
  pinMode(pirPin,INPUT);


  Serial.begin(115200);
  mq2.begin();
  dht.setup(dhtPin, DHTesp::DHT11);
  factor = analogRead(waterPin);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("...");

  }


}

void loop() {

  WiFiClient client;

  if (!client.connect(host, port)) {

        Serial.println("Connection to host failed");

        delay(500);
        return;
    }

    Serial.print("WiFi connected with IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


    float *values= mq2.read(true);


    Serial.print("Temperature:\t");
  Serial.println(getTemp());
    client.println(getTemp());

    Serial.print("Humidity:\t");
  Serial.println(getHum());
    client.println(getHum());

    Serial.print("movement:\t");
    Serial.println(getPir());
    client.println(getPir());

    Serial.print("Water state:\t");
  Serial.println(getWater());
    client.println(getWater());

    Serial.print("LPG:\t");
  Serial.println(getLPG());
    client.println(getLPG());

    Serial.print("Smoke:\t");
  Serial.println(getSmoke());
    client.println(getSmoke());

   Serial.print("CO:\t");
  Serial.println(getCO());
   client.println(getCO());

  delay(3000);


}
float getTemp(){
  return dht.getTemperature();
}
float getHum(){
  return dht.getHumidity();
}
int getWater(){
   int sensorValue = analogRead(waterPin)-factor;  
   int per= (sensorValue*100/4094);
   return map(per,0,33,0,100);
}


float getSmoke(){
  return mq2.smoke;
}
float getLPG(){     
  return mq2.lpg;
}
float getCO(){
  return mq2.co;
}
int getPir(){
  return (digitalRead(pirPin));
}
```

Comment: Does the PIR sensor require a pullup/pulldown resistor?

Comment: I think PIR sensor requires pull up resistor. if you don't connect it then reading will be different only.
Which PIR sensor module are using. Check if the module itself has PULL UP resistor.
If possible show us your hardware as well.

Comment: The sensor that im using is similar to this one: https://www.google.com/amp/s/lastminuteengineers.com/pir-sensor-arduino-tutorial/amp/